# Firebase push notification stop working after app is reinstall using flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I had configured FCM in my flutter app it works fine until I reinstall the app. When I reinstall app, it should stop receiving push notification from FCM. Also it show error on console unregistered notification for read_timeout. This is my AppDelegate.swift file.

```
import UIKit

import Flutter

import UserNotifications

import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain

@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

  override func application(

    _ application: UIApplication,

    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?

  ) -> Bool {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

           let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()



           center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in

               if error == nil{

                   UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

               }

           }



       }

       else {

           UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))

           UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

       }

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

  }

}
```

Comment: Did you update the FCM/Device Token, from where you are sending push i.e Server/Firebase?

Comment: firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((newToken) {
      subscribe(newToken);
    });

Comment: Have you tried to send push notification to the updated FCM/Device Token from Firebase Console?

Comment: You are facing this issue only on iOS right? Are you completed Push Notification Configuration Properly i.e Adding Push Notification Capability via XCode

Comment: Yes I config it completely, it receiving notification in previous version of but i can't understand why currently not receive notification for logout and re signin. in ios

Comment: can you plase tell me how token is refresh in ios?